# remapping multiple column values with multiple dictionary in dataframe using python pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

i have following dataframe format

```html
name,state,country
a,1,67
b,2,52
```

i have following state code and country code mapping dictionary

```html
state_map = { 1:'tn', 2:'kerala' }
country_map = { 67: 'usa', 52: 'india'
```

i have used data.replace({'state':state_map,'country':'country_map'})
its working if we give one column mapping but not working for multiple mapping dictionary

Comment: `if we give one column mapping but not working for multiple mapping dictionary` - can you explain more? I think solution should working nice - `data.replace({'state':state_map,'country':country_map})`

Comment: ya its working..i have given wrong mapping name..tq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) if giving a dict to replace:

- Nested dictionaries, e.g., {‘a’: {‘b’: nan}}, are read as follows:
  look in column ‘a’ for the value ‘b’ and replace it with nan. You can
  nest regular expressions as well. Note that column names (the
  top-level dictionary keys in a nested dictionary) cannot be regular
  expressions.

So for your case your dict looks like:

```
r_map = {'state':{'1':'tn', '2':'kerala'},'country':{'67':'usa', '52':'india'}}
```

Use it like this:

```
df.replace(r_map)
```

Answer (score 0):

The above solution takes lot of time, hence use below code instead for better performance(Note fillna used to fillup default values when match not found):-

```
df['state'].map(state_map).fillna(0)
df['country'].map(country_map).fillna(0)
```